# Need advice on sql server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Has anyone  an idea about how to get Table name and column name using sql server system tables?

Example : I know that a table somewhere in my database has a field containing an ID = 1125412.

Is there a way to run a global query on the database, to get column name and table name where this data exists.

Is this  doable, if you know a column name, and you want to know the table name to where it belongs?

Comment: You're saying that somewhere there is an integer stored which equals 1125412 but you don't know the column or table name? I've got a feeling you're going to need a cursor to do this... Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You can use a third party tool such as (free) Redgate SQL Search or see http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2

Comment: @Matthew PK: Joe says he knows the column name (ID). Couldn't he  query a system table to get all tables containing a column named ID, and then loop through those tables, possibly using a cursor as you suggest. It would probably be ugly, though.

Comment: @DOK: Hehe - that's precisely what I just wrote up. Definitely ugly.

Comment: @Martin Smith: SQL Search will not tell him which column has the data he is looking for. SQL Search will allow him to search the database for a given table,column,proc, view, etc whose name or text contains certain value but won't search the data, as Joe wants.

Comment: I think @Joe dev's only choice will be to write a loop but I'm pretty sure you can do this in a while loop instead of a cursor, which will be slower.

Comment: @Icarus - Ah OK. I haven't installed it. Obviously got the wrong impression of what it was about then. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **super** nasty, but it will work:

```
-- Finding all tables with an ID column
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id) SchemaName,
       T.name TableName
INTO #FoundTables
FROM sys.tables T INNER JOIN
     sys.columns C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
WHERE C.name = 'ID';

DECLARE @SchemaName NVarChar(100),
        @TableName NVarChar(100),
        @SQL NVarChar(2000);
-- Dynamically build a SELECT statement
WHILE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #FoundTables)) BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1 @SchemaName = SchemaName, @TableName = TableName,
    @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM $SchemaName.$TableName WHERE ID = 1125412;'
  FROM #FoundTables;

  SELECT @SQL =
    REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQL, '$SchemaName', @SchemaName), '$TableName', @TableName);
  EXEC (@SQL);

  DELETE FROM #FoundTables
  WHERE SchemaName = @SchemaName
    AND TableName = @TableName;
END;

DROP TABLE #FoundTables;
```

Comment: @Adrian: Haha, yes indeed. Assuming this code won't be put into production and is being used to locate a one-off data entry error :)

Comment: Ugly, indeed, but you gotta do what you gotta do ;) +1

Comment: +1 And should note that this is one of the few circumstances where a cursor is appropriate :D

Answer (score 0):

I use the following query:

```
SELECT  sys.sysobjects.id, 
    sys.sysobjects.name AS TableName, 
    sys.syscolumns.colid, 
    sys.syscolumns.name AS ColumnName, 
    sys.systypes.name AS DataType, 
    sys.syscolumns.isnullable AS AllowNull
FROM sys.syscolumns LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.systypes ON sys.syscolumns.xtype = sys.systypes.xtype 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.sysobjects ON sys.syscolumns.id = sys.sysobjects.id
WHERE (sys.sysobjects.xtype = 'U') AND (sys.systypes.name <> 'sysname')
ORDER BY TableName, sys.syscolumns.colid
```